# Must find out if now is the change than the one who is in the database

Tags: c#, datetime

It is such that I have no date in the database, and if it is less than the time / date as we have now so it must go in and refresh the use of the will rank 2. This means that we have, for example. the time is now and if it is not right than he who is in the database so it should not go in and do anything at all.

That means if the date looks like this is it too old.

3/15/2015 09:34:42 AM (it is now.) and 3/15/2015 04:34:42 AM

So it must go into the code to update the user **to get rank 2**

```
while (readerBrugere.Read())
  {
     string brugerid = readerBrugere["id"].ToString();
     DateTime brugerdato = Convert.ToDateTime(readerBrugere["trydato"].ToString());
     conn1.Close();

     if (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyHHmmss")) > Convert.ToDateTime(brugerdato))
     {
         int rankid = 2;

         cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE brugere SET rank = @rank WHERE Id = @brugerid;";
         cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rank", rankid);
         cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brugerid", brugerid);

         conn1.Open();
         cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
         conn1.Close();
     }
  }
```

It will only run content through if it is to time with me is right than what is in the database

Comment: `such that the jump on into my if if it is the user's date` is complete gibberish. Please correct it so that we can understand what you need.

Comment: there are some pointless DateTime converts in there.  DateTime To String to DateTime does nothing

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I've done that now and hope it's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text of your question hard to decipher, but looking at the code I can suggest a much-improved version:

```
while (readerBrugere.Read())
{
     //if these columns cannot be null, you should be able to use a simple cast
     int brugerid = (int)readerBrugere["id"];
     DateTime brugerdato = (DateTime)readerBrugere["trydato"];

      //don't close your database connection here

     //These values are *already* datetimes. There's not need to convert to datetime
     // and *especially* no need to convert to strings to compare them
     if (DateTime.Now > brugerdato)
     {
         // the "2" is a constant: just code it into the query that way
         string sql = "UPDATE brugere SET rank = 2 WHERE Id = @brugerid;";

         //or maybe you wanted this instead:
         string sql = "UPDATE brugere SET rank = rank + 1 WHERE Id = @brugerid;";

         //AddWithValue() kinda sucks somtimes. I prefer to do it like this instead:
         cmd1.Parameters.Add("@brugerid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = brugerid;

         //don't use the same connection as you did for the outer query:
         using (var cn2 = new SqlConnection(conn1.ConnectionString))
         using (var cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql, cn2))
         {
             cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
}
```

Finally, all this is really moot, as I expect you can do this entire process in the database with a single query:

```
UPDATE brugere
SET rank = rank + 1
WHERE trydato <= current_timestamp AND brugerdi IN 
   ( 
     ...existing query goes here, but only select the brugerdi column ... 
   )
```

Comment: Yeaa man. it works for me now and I no problems,!! :D Thanks for help!!